# Obtaining head and parts without evaluation

Tags: evaluation, hold

I have been trying to write a routine MyHead and MyPart
which would have the following properties.

```
MyHead[2+3]
```

evaluates to Plus

```
MyHead[(2+4)[10,11]]
```

evaluates to 2+4 (and not 6).

```
MyPart[f[2+3,10+11],1]
```

evaluates to 2+3

```
MyPart[f[2+3,10+11],2]
```

evaluates to 10+11

Ideally, this could be used to deeply
dive into an expression. For example, it could find the local variables
in the module

```
g[x_] := Module[{y,z,w},t];
```

from

```
Defintions[g]
```

I can't get it. Any suggestions?

Mark

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can capture but you can't return `2+4` unless you hold it somehow. I will use Hold for that purpose:

```
MyHead // Attributes = HoldAll;
MyHead[expr_] := MyPart[expr, 0]

MyPart // Attributes = HoldAll;
MyPart[expr_, spec__] := Hold[expr][[{1}, spec]]
```

It fits all your examples except it returns results wrapped with `Hold`. You can use `HoldForm` to not show it but the point holds.

Answer (score 5):

I tend to prefer [`Defer`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Defer.html) over [`Hold`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Hold.html) because it doesn't show in the output and the results can be used as new input without having to [release the hold](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReleaseHold.html) manually.

Other than that, the following is copied straight from [Kuba's solution](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/202330/26598):

```
MyHead // Attributes = HoldAll;
MyHead[expr_] := MyPart[expr, 0]
MyPart // Attributes = HoldAll;
MyPart[expr_, spec__] := Defer[expr][[{1}, spec]]

MyHead[2 + 3]
(*    Plus    *)

MyHead[(2 + 4)[10, 11]]
(*    2 + 4    *)

MyPart[f[2 + 3, 10 + 11], 1]
(*    2 + 3    *)

MyPart[f[2 + 3, 10 + 11], 2]
(*    10 + 11    *)
```